# Does `DataFrame.groupby*` in polars preserves the original order of rows within each group?

Tags: dataframe, rust, python-polars, rust-polars

The doc mentions that there are parameters to make groups maintain the original order. However, it is not clear on whether the original order of rows are preserved within each group.

Comment: I know that it does, but can't find anything in the docs to clarify this.

Comment: Answered by @ritchie46 for anyone reading: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9754#issuecomment-1624938834

Answer (score 0):

It maintains the order of elements in each group.

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": ["a", "b", "a", "b", "c"],
        "b": [1, 2, 1, 3, 3],
        "c": [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    }
).sort(["a", "c"], descending=True)

df.groupby("a", maintain_order=True).agg(pl.col("b"), pl.col("c")) 

shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ a   ┆ b         ┆ c         │
│ --- ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ str ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ c   ┆ [3]       ┆ [1]       │
│ a   ┆ [1, 1]    ┆ [5, 3]    │
│ b   ┆ [2, 3]    ┆ [4, 2]    │
└─────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```